# Template10 ModalDialog xaml error - Cannot create an abstract class

Tags: xaml, abstract, template10

I have a UWP application based on the Template10 hamburger template. I added the following modal dialog.

```
<Controls:ModalDialog x:Name="LoginModal"
                          CanBackButtonDismiss="False"
                          DisableBackButtonWhenModal="True">
        <Controls:ModalDialog.ModalContent>
            <views:LoginView x:Name="loginPart"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              HideRequested="LoginHide"
                              LoggedIn="LoginLoggedIn" />
        </Controls:ModalDialog.ModalContent>
    </Controls:ModalDialog>
```

My login view is declared like this

```
[Export]
public sealed partial class LoginView : Page, IView 
{
    ....
}
```

For some reason the xaml extract above gives me a design time error saying "Cannot create an abstract class." The project builds and runs ok but the xaml designer won't work.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LoginView would need to be a UserControl not a Page.  The other properties would be added to that codebehind of that usercontrol to allow for interaction with the ModalDialog

From the Samples folder... 
https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Samples/Search/Controls/LoginPart.xaml.cs

if this doesn't work then I would suspect the `MEF [Export]`